# Angular promise with a async/await failure

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-promise, ecmascript-5, strict

So far, the suggestions I've seen to remedy my issue don't seem to apply, or I have a big misunderstanding (I haven't touched full stack in quite a while). I've got a service that successfully hits a Spring Boot backend to get a list of processes:

```
function getReportProcesses(){
        var deferred =  $q.defer();
        var url = "fermentationReports/processes";
        httpService.get(url).then(function (data){
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }, function(msg){
            var errMsg  = "failed to get report processes: " +  msg;
            deferred.reject(errMsg);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

My objective is to hit the service from a dropdown factory, turn the list into JSON, and pass it to the dropdown as populated by the dropdown directive. When the directive calls the following line to get the JSON:

```
var data = ReportDdlFactory.getReportName();
            addAllTo(data, $scope.addAll);
```

it doesn't wait for the `httpService` in `getReportName()` to return before adding `data` as `undefined` to the scope. This is the original method in the factory:

```
function getReportName() {

            try {
                FermentationReportsService.getReportProcesses().then(function (data) {
                    if (data.processes !== undefined) {

                        var output = {"data": []};
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.processes.length; i++) {
                            var currentLine = {"value": data.processes[i], "label": data.processes[i]};
                            output.data.push(currentLine);
                        }
                        return output;

                    } else {
                        return {
                            "data": [
                                {"value": "ERROR OBTAINING PROCESSES", "label": "ERROR OBTAINING PROCESSES"}]
                        };
                    }
                });
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("error caught: " + err);
            }
        }
```

I tried to change it to use async/await since `getReportProcesses()` already returns a promise:

```
async getReportName() {

            try {
                await FermentationReportsService.getReportProcesses().then(function (data) {
                    if (data.processes !== undefined) {

                        var output = {"data": []};
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.processes.length; i++) {
                            var currentLine = {"value": data.processes[i], "label": data.processes[i]};
                            output.data.push(currentLine);
                        }
                        return output;

                    } else {
                        return {
                            "data": [
                                {"value": "ERROR OBTAINING PROCESSES", "label": "ERROR OBTAINING PROCESSES"}]
                        };
                    }
                });
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("error caught: " + err);
            }
        }
```

But I always get this from jshint:

```
 14 |            async getReportName() {
                 ^ Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
 14 |            async getReportName() {
                      ^ Missing semicolon.
 14 |            async getReportName() {
                                      ^ Missing semicolon.
 17 |                    await FermentationReportsService.getReportProcesses().then(function (data) {
                         ^ Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
 17 |                    await FermentationReportsService.getReportProcesses().then(function (data) {
                              ^ Missing semicolon.
  8 |                getReportName: getReportName,
                                    ^ 'getReportName' is not defined.
 14 |            async getReportName() {
                       ^ 'getReportName' is not defined.
 14 |            async getReportName() {
                 ^ 'async' is not defined.
```

I feel like I may be making this harder than it needs to be, or maybe I'm missing something simple?

---

**EDIT:**

After more research I determined that the app is running as `'strict'`, forcing ECMA 5. Is there an approach to force the response before continuing without using an ES6 approach?

Comment: You still need the `function` keyword when making it `async`. That being said, your problem in both cases is just that you don't return any value. You need to `return FermentationReportsService.getR...`. The Promise will then resolve to that value

Comment: this code it not clear for me so  if it possible share a complete version over https://stackblitz.com/ 

Comment: @blex thanks, I'll test that out.

Comment: @malbarmavi Sorry, I can't. Most of the code is proprietary and confidential as owned by the company I work for. I even had to obfuscate function names and such to safely post my issue here.

Comment: @blex when you say to `return FermentationReportsService.getR...`, I can't do that. It comes as a list, so I need to iterate over them and return the JSON object I created which happens after the for-loop. Does returning the `output` variable make the process invalid?

Comment: is FermentationReportsService is injected to the component ?? you may need to use this in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do something like this:

```
function getReportName() {
  return FermentationReportsService
    .getReportProcesses()
    .then(function(data) {
      if (data.processes === undefined) {
        return { data: [
          { value: "ERROR OBTAINING PROCESSES", label: "ERROR OBTAINING PROCESSES" }
        ]};
      }
      
      return {
        data: data.processes.map(function(process) {
                return { value: process.value, label: process.value };
              })
      };
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("error caught: " + err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks blex. I did some more digging and determined that this is running as 'strict', using ES5 and so these approaches are apparently disallowed in my position. Do you know of a way that uses ES5 keywords only? Apparently, the arrow, await, async, etc aren't allowed, and jshint doesn't recognize them as legal keywords.

Comment: @DarrelHolt I've edited the answer, this should work

Comment: The app builds correctly and passes the jshint, but it's still hitting the directive line that adds `data` to the scope before executing `getReportName()`. the `data` object also has this structure: `{
    "$$state": {
        "status": 0
    }
}`. Should I make the calling method to the `getReportName()` within the directive async so it waits as well?

Comment: Oh yes I forgot this part. This function returns a Promise, so it's asynchronous. You'll need to do something along these lines: `ReportDdlFactory.getReportName().then(function(data) { addAllTo(data, $scope.addAll); });`

Comment: Thanks, you got it. there were a few more methods called that used the `data` variable in the directive so I put those in the `then` method and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

by using async/await you no longer need to use **then**

```js
async function getReportName() {
  try {
    const data = await FermentationReportsService.getReportProcesses();
    if (data.processes !== undefined) {
      var output = { data: [] };
      for (var i = 0; i < data.processes.length; i++) {
        var currentLine = {
          value: data.processes[i],
          label: data.processes[i],
        };
        output.data.push(currentLine);
      }
      return output;
    } else {
      return {
        data: [
          {
            value: 'ERROR OBTAINING PROCESSES',
            label: 'ERROR OBTAINING PROCESSES',
          },
        ],
      };
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error caught: ' + err);
  }
}
```

check this article for more info  [javascript.info async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Comment: Thanks, I'm seeing that my jshint is still complaining. First, it's saying this about async in the function header: `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`. Followed by `async` is not defined.  As well as `'const' is available in ES6`. Is `async` something that needs to be defined or included in the module factory header? Also it want a semicolon after `await` on the line `const data = await FermentationReportsService.getReportProcesses();`

Comment: is getReportName part of class ? if so you need to **remove** the function keyword but I'm not sure because you don't share the full source of the component in case you are using angular 

Comment: Thank you guys for your help thus far. I did some more digging and determined that this is running as 'strict', using ES5 and so these approaches are apparently disallowed in my position. Do you know of a way that uses ES5? Apparently, the arrow, await, async, etc aren't allowed and jshint doesn't recognize them as legal keywords.